# Add 2 input values and show total

Tags: html, forms

I have 2 'time' inputs for a start and end time.

When both inputs are completed I am wanting the 'total' field to automatically show the total between start and end (e.g 8 hours)

```
<input type='time' value="09:00" id="MondayStart" name='MondayStart' class='form-control'>
<input type='time' value="17:00" name='MondayEnd' id="MondayEnd" class='form-control'>
<input type="text" name="total">
```

I have tried following this script (http://jsbin.com/emoziw/1/edit?html,js,output) but cannot seem to change it to time

Comment: Removed the Java tag - apologies, though java would be used to achieve the aim

Comment: `"Can this be done?"` - Sure, you just have to write code to do it.  Have you tried anything at all?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: see updated question @David

Comment: Shane, you're not new here, and so you probably already know that all code must be posted as code-formatted text in your question, not in a link. Thank you in advance for fixing this soon.

Comment: @Shane: "I cannot seem to change it to time" isn't really a question we can answer.  What specific code are you using and in what specific way is it failing?

Comment: random down votes I swear ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a default value so this is good.
You need to do something like this (using jQuery) :

```
$(".form-control").on('change', ()=>{
  var $this = $(this);
  var sum;
  sum = /*do the sum calculation here*/;
  $('input[name="total"]').eq(0).val(sum);
  //if you put an id to the total then you can just use $(id here).val(sum)
});
```

This will, when the `change` event is triggered on any element having the `form-control` class, update the sum automatically.

PS:

I suggest to put a default value on the sum's holder (being of course the sume of the default values)

EDIT

I'd like to help you with the time calculation, so I made functions :

```
function doCalc($jq){//pass in the jqSelection that gets the two input
  var $beg = $jq.eq(0);//first element with this class
  var $end = $jq.eq(1);//second element with this class

  var beg_t = {
    h: getH($beg),
    m: getM($beg)
  }

  var end_t = {
    h: getH($end),
    m: getM($end)
  }

  var elapsed = {
    h: end_t.h - beg_t.h,
    m: end_t.m - beg_t.m
  }

  return ""+elapsed.h+":"+elapsed.m;//so it can be used with what's above
}
```

/

```
function getH($t){
  var str = $t.val();
  return str.replace(/(\d{2}):(\d{2})/,"$1");
}

function getM($t){
  var str = $t.val();
  return str.replace(/(\d{2}:(\d{2})/,"$2");
}
```

EDIT 2:

If you want you can pass to the onchange EH a function pointer (therefore you can also call the function without having to trigger the event) :

```
function updateSum(){
  var $this = $(".form-control");
  var sum;
  sum = doCalc($this);
  $('input[name="total"]').eq(0).val(sum);
  //if you put an id to the total then you can just use $(id here).val(sum)
}
```

therefore you can have :

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
  updateSum();
  $(".form-control").on('change', updateSum);
});
```

EDIT 3:

`()=>{/*...*/}` is just the ES6 way to declare an anonymous function, you can replace them with `function(){/*...*/}` if you're more comfortable with it.

EDIT 4 aka **RECAP** :

If you're a bit lost after this answer, here's a recap of the functions you need to add to your website :

**@@Regex based input processing@@**

```
function getH($t){
  var str = $t.val();
  return str.replace(/(\d{2}):(\d{2})/,"$1");
}

function getM($t){
  var str = $t.val();
  return str.replace(/(\d{2}:(\d{2})/,"$2");
}
```

**@@Calculation@@**

```
function doCalc($jq){//pass in the jqSelection that gets the two input
  var $beg = $jq.eq(0);//first element with this class
  var $end = $jq.eq(1);//second element with this class

  var beg_t = {
    h: getH($beg),
    m: getM($beg)
  }

  var end_t = {
    h: getH($end),
    m: getM($end)
  }

  var elapsed = {
    h: end_t.h - beg_t.h,
    m: end_t.m - beg_t.m
  }

  return ""+elapsed.h+":"+elapsed.m;//so it can be used with what's above
}
```

**@@Update function@@**

```
function updateSum(){
  var $this = $(".form-control");
  var sum;
  sum = doCalc($this);
  $('input[name="total"]').eq(0).val(sum);
  //if you put an id to the total then you can just use $(id here).val(sum)
}
```

**@@Event Handling and Call@@**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  updateSum();
  $(".form-control").on('change', updateSum);
});
```